# Javascript date format not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, locale

I changed the code. I have this function:

```js
    function Date(stringDate){
        var date=moment(stringDate).locale('es').format('DD MMM');
        if(date=="Invalid Date"){
            return '-';
        } else {
            return date;
        }
    
    }
```

It still returns the date in english.

Comment: You won't get that out of that function, because **month names are not capitalized in spanish**. The formatting is doing its job. You _could_ use `string.replace()` to capitalize it yourself.

Comment: Unrelated to your locale question, why are you comparing new Date() with the string "Invalid Date"?

Comment: @jarmod: See my answer for a possible extension to this function with `new Date()` a default parameter, but allowing for you to supply the date.  In this case, `== 'Invalid Date'` actually does the job, even if it is... odd.

Comment: @ScottSauyet OK, seems like an alternative to isNaN(date). I made my original comment, of course,  because the given code could not yield an invalid date and it wasn't clear that the OP knew that and had not simply block-copied from somewhere on the internet.

Comment: @jarmod—I agree that `isNaN(date)` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Note the caveats in the comments about this being the incorrect version for Spanish.

But if you still want to do this, using a regular expression replacement on the result of the above is probably the easiest.   This is a slightly different formulation of your version, with that replace call added.  It also allows you to supply the date, defaulting to today if one isn't supplied:

```js
let formatDate = (date = new Date()) => date == "Invalid Date" 
  ? '-' 
  : date.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {day: 'numeric', month: 'short'})
    .replace(/\b([a-z])/, (s, w) => w.toUpperCase())
    
console.log(formatDate())
console.log(formatDate(new Date(1776, 7, 4)))
console.log(formatDate(new Date(1862, 4, 5)))
console.log(formatDate(new Date('foo-bar-baz')))
```

Comment: If they are using an i18n tool to localize text, I highly recommend parsing the text and modifying it. Will be very sensitive to any changes in code (brittle)

Comment: Absolutely.  And I think the code would likely be better for that.  This is a very specific solution to a problem that likely should not be fixed.  If the OP does want to "fix" the lower-case names issue for that particular Spanish format, this should work.  I'd suggest that the OP look to something different, though.

Comment: I really don't understand the attraction of this kind of function expression. A function declaration with clear statements and *if* block is more readable and maintainable, and probably is more efficient.

Comment: @RobG: I wrote that version to include as a comment and then realized what I wanted to say was too long for that.  I don't know if I would choose to change it back, though.  I'm very much in favor of removing as much control flow as I can from my code.  I've built an [entire library](https://ramdajs.com) on such principles.  However, I'm curious as to whether you know of references to the relative efficiencies.